# Need help calling a method

Tags: c#, winforms, methods

I am trying to upload a picture to a winform and then show a thumbnail.  I tried adding the functionality to my btnUpload_click method but it would not allow me to set PaintEventArgs as an eventhandler.  So to remedy this, I created another method but now need to know how to call it.

```
private void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{}

public void getImage(PaintEventArgs ex)
{
    Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort myCallback =
    new Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort(ThumbnailCallback);

    OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
    // image filters
    open.Filter = "Image Files(*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.gif; *.bmp)|*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.gif; *.bmp";
    if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        // display image in picture box
        upload = new Bitmap(open.FileName);

        pictureBox1.Image.GetThumbnailImage(114, 108, myCallback, IntPtr.Zero);
        ex.Graphics.DrawImage(upload, 150, 75);
    }
}
```

Thank you for your assistance

Comment: Have you tried `getImage((PaintEventAgs) e);` inside `btnUpload_Click` ?

Comment: @evanmcdonnal That will just throw at runtime.

Comment: Why do you need PaintEventArgs? Assign your image to some pictureBox or your form's backgroundImage.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `PaintEventArgs` for a `Graphics` instance. Just change the code to work inside the button click:

```
Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort myCallback =
    new Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort(ThumbnailCallback);

OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();

// image filters
open.Filter = "Image Files(*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.gif; *.bmp)|*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.gif; *.bmp";
if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    // display image in picture box
    upload = new Bitmap(open.FileName);

    pictureBox1.Image.GetThumbnailImage(114, 108, myCallback, IntPtr.Zero);
    this.CreateGraphics().DrawImage(upload, 150, 75);
}
```

Comment: `DrawImage` this way won't work if user move the form or does anything so that the `Paint` event is fired.

Comment: @KingKing, of course there are issues with the image getting redrawn, but the OP doesn't need `PaintEventArgs`. I don't know anything about the program and the persistence the OP already has in place. This solves the OP's problem.

Comment: Using this snippit throws an Object reference not set to an object error at the line: pictureBox1.Image.GetThumbnailImage(114, 108, myCallback, IntPtr.Zero);

Comment: @user2379048, and that's likely because `Image` is `null`. But that's because you didn't set it here. I simply took the code you gave us and showed you how to get a `Graphics` object without the `PaintEventArgs`. If the code doesn't logically fit into the program you'll need to rework it.